# QDockWidget change both windowTitle

Tags: windows, qt, qdockwidget

I have a class that derives from `QDockWidget`.

In the constructor of my custom class I pass 
also the title to `QDockWidget` contructor and set the `windowTitle`.
At runtime I can change the `windowTitle` of the undocked window
but this doesn't change the title of the docked header.

Comment: What means `title of the docked header`?

Comment: when i call setWindowTitle(title) this doesnt change the dockwidget title, when my widget is docked. i only see the new title when i undock the widget

Comment: or should i call something to update/repaint window title

Comment: Could you please show us some codes about how you did that? I've done a test and it worked well.